# What is the most accurate translation for "vai dar" and "falar merda"?

Tags: tradução, coloquialismos

What is the meaning of this sentence?

> Vai dar merda se você ficar falando merda

Comment: Those are two separate questions and we don't usually do translation here into English. If you keep talking shit, you'll get shit.

Comment: What have you tried? How far did you get? We don't do translations of sentences, but we can help with a particular word or, if you do part of the job, we can help finish with a particular difficulty of translation.

Answer (score 2):

"Dar", just like "to give", has many meanings, especially when part of expressions. Some of these meanings are ([Aulete 13., 28.; 21](https://www.aulete.com.br/dar), [Priberam 9., 11., 22.](https://dicionario.priberam.org/dar)):

> to cause, to generate, to result in, to provoke, to produce, to originate, to bear

So, "dar merda" means something like "to get screwed up", "to end up in shit" or, in less coarse language, "to end up badly", "to not end up well".

As for "falar merda", it can be rather literally translated as "to talk shit" or "to bullshit", or also "to talk nonsense".

This way, "Vai dar merda se você ficar falando merda" could be translated as "It's gonna end up in shit if you keep talking shit" or, one of DeepL many suggestions, "It's gonna get fucked up if you keep talking shit" or, if you don't want to risk offending anyone and don't mind losing the original tone, "It'll end up badly if you keep talking nonsense".

Answer (score 0):

Something like: "If you talk bullshit, you'll get bullshit." Don't say what you shouldn't, if you do it you'll probably have problems. Like as: don't talk about your boss without looking back. Do you get it?

Answer (score -1):

Vai dar merda é uma expressão muito popular na língua portuguesa, significa que vai ter problemas, a situação vai ficar complicada. Vai dar é outra expressão, é algo que vai acontecer, ou ato sexual referindo-,se ao gênero feminino.

Comment: Olá Alessandra, boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE. Note que a pergunta foi feita em inglês e, portanto, uma resposta em português é de utilidade limitada.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).